# Integral of pointwise limit is not the point wise limit of the integral.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, pointwise-convergence

> I want to find a sequence of measurable non negative functions $(f_n)$ with point wise limit a.e. such that the integral of the limit is different to the limit of the integrals and both limits are finite.

So I thought I could just let $f_n = \frac{1}{n}\chi_{(0,n)}$. On one hand, 
$$\lim_n f_n = 0$$
and so, $\int \lim_n f_n = \int 0 = 0$. But for each $n$,
$$\int f_n = \frac{1}{n}\mu((0,n)) = \frac{n}{n} = 1$$
and therefore, $\lim_n \int f_n = \lim_n 1 = 1$.

Is this correct? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct.  This example, which I like to call the "melting ice cube," is a good example of a sequence of functions that converge pointwise almost everywhere (indeed, the sequence converges *everywhere*, and even uniformly so!), but which fails to converge in $L^1$ (in particular, you cannot pass the limit through the integral).

Another nice example is the "traveling box" example.  Let $f_n = \chi_{[n,n+1]}$.  Observe that $f_n \to 0$ pointwise, but
$$ \int f_n = \int \chi_{[n,n+1]} = m([n,n+1]) = 1,$$
where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.  The traveling box is maybe slightly more interesting as a counter-example, as the convergence is *not* uniform (though it is still pointwise).